# Boot timeout countdown not working

Tags: boot

I use Macrium Reflect v6 on my Win 8.1 Pro 64-bit machine which offers a Boot Recovery Menu to choose to boot from Win 8.1 or Macrium Reflect recovery environment. Normally there is a 'Windows will start in 10 secs ...' message (depending on value in msconfig / Boot timeout (delay) value. However this is no longer working. It is as if the timeout countdown / delay aborts (I just see the message flash up and disappear instantly) and I have to manually select the Win 8.1 boot option. I am not sure if this started after a (first) Macrium Reflect restore, or after I changed the timeout value. I can change the value easily enough but any idea how to reinstate the countdown - something may have corrupted or be interfering with this. I have posted also on Macrium support forum but I think it may not be Macrium, but something else on my Windows machine.

Comment: The first thing I'd check is to make sure you don't have any stuck keys on your keyboard. With the computer on or off (your choice, though I suggest off), press each key on the keyboard once, and ensure that it returns properly to its rest position when released. This is a little far-fetched, but it's easy to check and absolutely won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

There are many settings in BCD which can cause timeout to be ignored.

Things are pretty complex in Windows 8 and later with the introduction of "metro" or graphic style boot menu !

Usually for timeout to play there must be a choice of boot loaders (minimum two). The choice is set in {bootmgr} - element "DisplayOrder".

DisplayOrder is a list of GUIDs of loaders (e.g. "Windows 8", "Windows 7").

Every GUID in DisplayOrder must be present as object in BCD.

The "DefaultObject" element of {bootmgr} holds the GUID of the default loader object which must be present also in DisplayOrder.

{bootmgr} element "Timeout" must be >0 and so the choice which should be present in "DisplayOrder" will be presented either

a) at once if text style boot menu (Windows 7 style boot menu) is set for the default loader

b) or will be presented later in a graphical style if the default loader has element "BootMenuPolicy" set to "Standard" (not "Legacy"!)

There are also other elements which can interfere on the style of boot menu and timeout !

If the default loader has "BootMenuPolicy" set to "Standard" additional dll's are loaded before the boot menu is displayed !
So here all necessary dll's must be present or else there will be a problem displaying the graphic style boot menu.

In the case of BootMenuPolicy=Legacy bootmgr displays the text style boot menu without loading anything else (after reading BCD).

Countdown of time out starts after displaying of boot menu either text or graphic.

Huh !

For viewing complete BCD (and editing it) [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) could be used.

Hint: BootMenuPolicy is element with id 0x250000c2 (value 0-legacy, 1-standard)

Other settings which can interfere on boot menu style (and timeout) are {emssettings}, element "DisplayBootMenu" of {bootmgr} object and maybe others.